# Custom sorting logic for groups using CollectionViewSource

Tags: wpf, grouping, collectionviewsource

I have a list of "stuff" which needs to be filtered then displayed in a grouped and sorted manner. The data needed to calculate the grouping and sorting order is not available as simple properties - there needs to be some work done in code to calculate the order and groups.

CollectionViewSource lets me define custom filter and sort logic - so far so good. It also lets me bind GroupDescriptions to a value converter so that I can generate the group names.

The last thing I want to do is control the order that the generated groups appear and this is causing me pain!

Everything I see about [CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742542.aspx) says that it will sort groups by a **property** name, but I don't have a property available to sort by. SortDescriptions can't be bound to a value converter like GroupDescriptions can and I'm out of other ideas.

So - how do you implement custom sorting logic of CollectionViewSource groups?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[This post on Bea Stollnitz' blog](https://web.archive.org/web/20120626061539/http://bea.stollnitz.com/blog/?p=17), [and the GitHub repo](https://github.com/bstollnitz/old-wpf-blog/tree/master/14-SortingGroups), demonstrates how you can do that. You will have to sort by the criteria of your grouping first. Even if this is not a concrete property, it should be possible to sort your items using the same logic that you use to group them, isn't it?! Certainly, this is not possible using a SortDescription instance, but you could instead use the [`ListCollectionView.CustomSort`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.listcollectionview.customsort.aspx) property and specify an appropriate `IComparer` implementation.

Comment: That didn't seem to work for me when I tried it, but I'll go back and take another look, since I've tried a bunch of other stuff since then and it's quite possible I missed something...

Comment: Well, it works for me. Maybe you could post some code, then we could try to find your problem.

Comment: OK, I had a "couldn't see the wood for the trees" moment. Thanks - after clearing out all the cruft that did what I was looking for.

Comment: That webpage is not longer available.